# Is this a good DRY method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry, mixins, yield, assets

I don't want use a `//= require_tree .` (because it loads all the assets I have, which I also don't need) and don't want write each time `javasctipt_include_tag("my_controller")`. So I decided to do following:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def add_asset(*files)
    puts "DEBUG: add: " + files.to_s

    content_for(:html_head) do
      if GtFe::Application.assets.find_asset(*files)
        yield :asset_include_tag
      end
    end
  end

  def javascript(*files)
    add_asset(*files) do
      content_for :asset_include_tag
        javascript_include_tag(*files)
    end
  end

  def stylesheet(*files)
    add_asset(*files) do
      content_for :asset_include_tag
        stylesheet_link_tag(*files)
    end
  end

end
```

So I use name named yields in helper methods and I have a main `add_asset()` method and two asset-specific methods. Is it a good way to do so? Or are any better solutions available?

## Update:

From the rails docs:

> For example, if you generate a ProjectsController, Rails will also add
>   a new file at app/assets/javascripts/projects.js.coffee and another at
>   app/assets/stylesheets/projects.css.scss. By default these files will
>   be ready to use by your application immediately using the require_tree
>   directive. See Manifest Files and Directives for more details on
>   require_tree.
>
> You can also opt to include controller specific stylesheets and
>   JavaScript files only in their respective controllers using the
>   following: <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %> or <%=
>   stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>. Ensure that you are not
>   using the require_tree directive though, as this will result in your
>   assets being included more than once.

So the `javascript_include_tag` and `stylesheet_link_tag` are justified. But is it good so to do this yield staff to DRY?

## Update2:

I landed with this code refinements:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def add_asset(asset_type, *files)
    puts "DEBUG: add #{asset_type} files: #{files}"

    content_for(:html_head) do
      files.each do |file|

        puts "DEBUG: now add #{asset_type}: #{file}"

        if GtFe::Application.assets.find_asset(file)
          yield(:asset_include_tag, file)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def javascript(*files)
    add_asset("js", *files) do
      content_for :asset_include_tag
        javascript_include_tag
    end
  end

  def stylesheet(*files)
    add_asset("css", *files) do
      content_for :asset_include_tag
        stylesheet_link_tag
    end
  end

end
```

And then I can write in each view/layout so:

```
= javascript(params[:controller], "#{params[:controller]}_#{params[:action]}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is overkill.

If you don't like require full tree unordered, you can require them manually one by one.

```
//= js_file_a
//= js_file_b
```

Comparing with your solution:

1. you still need typing the file names by yourself.

   ```
   def add_asset(*files)
   ```
2. Several unnecessary helpers added when the jobs can be done elsewhere easily.

Comment: in the controller-specific css?